# Java CEF Hangs on createClient()

Tags: java, chromium-embedded

I am writing an application that uses the CEF library to embed a chrome browser into my desktop application, but the program keeps getting hung up the line of code where the client is created.

```
cApp = CefApp.getInstance();
client = cApp.createClient();
browser = client.createBrowser("http://www.google.com/", false, false);
browserUI = browser.getUIComponent();
browserUI.setBounds(5, 5, 640, 360);
```

This is the code I have, it gets through the `CefApp.getInstance()` but gets stuck on the next line of code. There is no error or anything in the console, just endless waiting. Any solutions?